# What is the relationships between Android-Activity and Android-Fragment; Activity/Fragment and ViewModel in UML class diagram?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, uml, class-diagram

Let's see a brief explanation about these terms in a nutshell.

1. Android-Activity is independent, it can present the view itself.
2. Android-Fragment can't run independently and requires an  Android-activity as its host, which means that when the  Android-activity is/was destroyed then the  Android-fragment will be too. The  Android-fragment does not strictly specify which  Android-activity should or can host it, as long as it is an  Android-activity then you're good.
3. Both  Android-activity and  Android-fragment can have ViewModel.
4. ViewModel is always dependent on  Android-activity or  Android-fragment lifecycle, which means that when the  Android-activity/ Android-fragment is/was destroyed then the ViewModel will be destroyed as well (except for configuration changes).

Let's see some relationships defined in the UML class diagram.

1. Composition (not sure, since the  Android-activity doesn't depend on the  Android-fragment)
2. Aggregation (not sure, since the  Android-fragment will be destroyed if the  Android-activity destroyed the same with the ViewModel, where aggregation encourage that both parties can live with its own)
3. Association (maybe yes or no?)
4. Dependency (maybe yes or no?)
5. <s>Generalization (definitely no)</s>
6. <s>Realization (definitely no)</s>

Now, to model them on UML Class Diagram, there are some questions:

- What is the relationship between the  Android-activity and the Android-fragment?
- What is the relationship between the  Android-activity/ Android-fragment and ViewModel?

Comment: "it is mean that when the activity/fragment was destroyed then the ViewModel too", No, in case config change like rotation device activity and fragment destroy but view model still alive

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your question, considering the amount of terrible posts we see each day, this one is well defined and researched, so i've removed the top part of your post. i'm not entirely sure if this post belongs on stack overflow though, it might be migrated by someone more knowledgeable :)

Comment: I edited your question to add the prefix  "Android-" to not confuse with UML-activity and UML-(combined)fragment

Comment: @CôngHải are you sure of you ? in that case the answer is false too

Comment: Your question implicitly consider Android-activity and Android-fragment are modeled through UML-classes, are you sure of that ?

Comment: @bruno sure, "ViewModel objects are automatically retained during configuration changes so that data they hold is immediately available to the next activity or fragment instance", check this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement

Comment: @a_local_nobody I put the sentence so people don't downvote my question right before they read it. Anyway thanks for the edits, I appreciate it, I guess my grammar is very bad.

Comment: @bruno yep, I mean activity and fragment in Android, thanks for clarifying, I appreciate it

Comment: @CôngHải I've missed that one, thanks for clarifying, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, the appropriate relationship is a composition, because the child is destroyed when the parent is destroyed.

[image: cd1]

Multiplicity `1` means that every Fragment requires an Activity.

Multiplicity `0..*` means that multiple Fragments can be part of the same Activity, but an Activity does not necessarily have any Fragment.

The relationships for ViewModel are as follows:

[image: cd3]

UPDATE: In your question, you have added an exception for configuration changes. In that case, the relationships with ViewModel are not compositions. But if you don't want to let this exception influence your model, you could add a note in the diagram explaining the exception.

Comment: considering you've given an answer to this and you're on both platforms, do you consider this question off-topic for SO ? would it not fit better in software engineering, perhaps ? i consider this more of a theory question

Comment: I agree with you, but there has been some debate in the past. Some UML experts have a lot of reputation on SO and not on SE and they want to continue here.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Thanks for the answer, I'm still learning about UML class diagrams. Do you mean that every time there is a class (e.g: class B) that depends on another class (e.g: class A) and is also destroyed at the same time, even if A can run independently without B (or when A reaches its life limit) it will be considered that B is the composition of class A? Therefore their relationship is composition, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: In UML, we say that class A depends on class B if (the implementation of) class A has a reference to class B, i.e. you cannot implement class A without also implementing class B. In your question, you wrote that Activity does not _depend on_ Fragment. If that just means that Activity may have zero Fragments, then forget about my remark about the cross. If you meant to say that class Activity does not have any knowledge about class Fragment, then my remark about the cross is relevant. But even then, the cross is not used very often.

Comment: I am not a native speaker of English, maybe I use the wrong words to explain the relationship between the Activity and Fragment (I hope not).

I do not mean to say that the Activity do not depend on the Fragment at all, in theory, yes that is true, but in practice, the Activity has references to the Fragment (for example: in class attributes), and the Fragment is needed to present the view to the user.

Comment: In Android, there are times when we destroy the Fragment instances when they are not needed anymore, but it does not affect the life of the Activity which means that it can run without the presence of the Fragment. It just makes the view that is part of the Fragment empty. This is the reason why I say that the Activity does not "depend" on the Fragment.

Comment: OK, then forget about the cross notation. I have deleted it from my answer. If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I'm sorry, I just saw your updated answer, so in that case, what is the relationship between the Activity/Fragment and ViewModel?